# How to make dynamic file name import in webpack work in production?

Tags: javascript, css, vue.js, webpack, tree-shaking

I have this script that loads a css file based on passed string and it works locally without tree-shaking:

```js
export function applyCSS(filename) {
  try {
    require(`../styles/${filename}.css`);
  } catch {
    require(`../styles/default.css`);
  }
}
```

This works locally but never in production. I never see the `styles` folder in `dist` folder. Is there a way for webpack to make it include that folder or maybe a better approach for this?

Comment: Deleted my answer bc do not accurate address a solution. I'm commenting instead. Try putting your styles folder under a "public" folder at **the same level as your src folder, not inside src** All the content of the public folder should end up bundled in the root path of your app at runtime. Please note that with this approach everyone will be able to see your stylesheets.

Comment: https://webpack.js.org/guides/asset-modules/